# Create columns in dataframe based on csv field

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with the column "Values" that has comma separated values:

```
Row|Values
1|1,2,3,8
2|1,4
```

I want to create columns based on the CSV, and assign a boolean indicating if the row has that value, as follows:

```
Row|1,2,3,4,8
1|true,true,true,false,true
2|true,false,false,true,false
```

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using [`get_dummies`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html), check the link here and the `astype(bool)` change 1 to True 0 to False

```
df.set_index('Row')['Values'].str.get_dummies(',').astype(bool)
Out[318]: 
        1      2      3      4      8
Row                                  
1    True   True   True  False   True
2    True  False  False   True  False
```

Comment: @pygo Just the base usage for get_dummies function , I will add the link